# Good drills to strengthen my non dominant hand in basketball

Tags: basketball, training

What are some good drills that I can do in basketball to strengthen my ball handling skills with my non dominant hand? Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the best way to train non-dominant hand/foot is with the very basic, beginning drills that are used to teach the skill for one's dominant hand/foot.  Whatever drills you started with, switch hands and be deliberate about it. This is not fun work.  Your brain and body already know what to do, but now your body is not doing what you know it can do.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I appreciate the answer and I will work on this. I had tryouts last night and again today for high school basketball and I haven't played in awhile, so I want to increase my chance to make it onto the team.